# No puedo disparar el error 500 en produccion, solo lo veo en development

Tags: build, nextjs

Quiero probar la pagina de error 500, para ello intento lanzar un error desde alguna pagina de mi aplicacion, en la funcion `getStaticProps`. Originalmente la funcion `getStaticsProps` es esta:

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {    
  const canonicalUrl = `${process.env.CW_BASE_URL}/search`;
  return {
    props: {
      pageData: {
        canonicalUrl,
        pageSlug: "/search",
      },
      isSearchPage: true,
    },
    revalidate: parseInt(process.env.STATIC_REGEN_TIME || "240", 10),
  };
};
```

Ahora le hago esta modificacion:

```
 export const getStaticProps = async () => {
      function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
       }
      if (getRandomInt(10) === 5) {
          throw new Error("Internal Server Error");
      }
    
      const canonicalUrl = `${process.env.CW_BASE_URL}/search`;
      return {
        props: {
          pageData: {
            canonicalUrl,
            pageSlug: "/search",
          },
          isSearchPage: true,
        },
        revalidate: parseInt(process.env.STATIC_REGEN_TIME || "240", 10),
      };
   };
```

Si yo intento ahora acceder a la pagina que tiene la funcion `getStaticProps`, (en desarrollo con `npm run dev`) la app se rompe. La idea es que yo arme la build, y en lugar de romperse, pueda ver la pagina custom de error 500. Pero el error jamas se dispara.

Alguien me podría orientar sobre como puedo simular ese error en producción? (Si no armo la build y la pruebo en desarrollo, no veo la pagina de error personalizada, sino que veo el típico error de React cuando se rompe la aplicación)

Comment: Bueno me lo solucionó un compañero por fuera de S.O asi que dejo la respuesta en el comentario por si alguien quiere explayarse y dejar una respuesta. La solucion es extremadamente sencilla. ``getStaticProps`` esta devolviendo una pagina estatica por ende nunca lanza el error, se arma la buid devolviendo false en la condicion del error (sino ni se arma) y queda asi siempre. La solucion es reemplazar la funcion por ``getServerSideProps`` (solo reemplazar el nombre), esa funcion sí va a generar un numero random en cada refresh de la app, y entonces el error se genera luego de algunos refresh

Comment: Cabe aclarar que esta solucion, si bien puede afectar nuestro normal comportamiento de la app (en mi caso se rompen algunas cosas si uso getServerSideProps en lugar de getStaticProps) es valida porque yo solo quiero ver como se comporta el error en produccion. Una vez testeado el mismo, vuelvo a dejar mi funcion getStaticProps como estaba, pero ya se que ante cualquier error 500 voy a ver el componente que necesito

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es extremadamente sencilla. `getStaticProps` está devolviendo una página estática por ende nunca lanza el error, se arma la buid devolviendo false en la condición del error (sino ni se arma) y queda asi siempre. La solución es reemplazar la función por getServerSideProps (solo reemplazar el nombre), esa función sí va a generar un numero random en cada refresh de la app, y entonces el error se genera luego de algunos refresh.

Cabe aclarar que esta solución, si bien puede afectar nuestro normal comportamiento de la app (en mi caso se rompen algunas cosas si uso `getServerSideProps` en lugar de `getStaticProps`) es válida porque yo solo quiero ver como se comporta el error en producción. Una vez testeado el mismo, vuelvo a dejar mi función `getStaticProps` como estaba, pero ya se que ante cualquier `error 500` voy a ver el componente que necesito.

> Respuesta sacada de 2 comentarios de [Agustin G.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/143803/agustin-g)